What happens to the scrotum of neutered dogs?
I am not sure which stack this belongs on. The only other stack I could find that has questions regarding veterinary medicine is the Academia Stack Exchange, and I feel like the medical stack is much better suited for this question than the academia stack. Just let me know if this belongs elsewhere.
I just got my newest addition neutered, so he has a "deflated" scrotum dangling between his legs. I have had newly neutered dogs before, but in the one case, it was a puppy, and in the other case, it was a tiny chihuahua. In both of those cases, there was pretty much no leftover sack. I talked to two friends who have had larger dogs neutered and they assured me that the empty scrotum "goes away." So, this left me wondering, what happens to it? Does it just get absorbed into the body, or what? Does that skin in that area remain as stretchy as if it were a scrotum? Does necrosis take over and the cells don't replicate properly? And, lastly (maybe this is worth a separate question), what happens to human scrota who have to be castrated (usually due to testicular cancer)? Does their scrota go away like dogs.
Currently, it seems like his scrotum is shrinking. I just want to know what's going on biologically with him, and also if human bodies react the same way.
As for what I have done to research this myself, I've looked at tons (50+) websites that discuss what happens, but I haven't found anything that explains the biology behind it.
The place I have found that discusses scrotal shrinkage in the most detail is VetAdvises.com, but the only explanation given is that a reduction in testosterone causes shrinkage.
Most places seem to agree that the scrotum will shrink, but I find NOTHING on why that is or what is happening biologically in the scrotum. For example, ZooNerdy, pawsafe.com, PetMD, and Chewy.com.
Whereas, a lot of other sites don't even mention scrotal shrinkage, such as PetPlace, AnimalHumaneSociety.or, and Zoetispetcare.com.
All-in-all I can't find any place discussing why scrotal shrinkage occurs.

You've got a lot of hearsay here from friends and such but no actual attempt to find an answer, which you know this site requires. Hint: Your friends are wrong.

@CareyGregory Thanks for keeping me honest. I did look before i came here, I just forgot to add that bit. As for them being wrong, they watched the process happen to their dogs. Also, I saw it to very slight degree in my chihuahua. In addition, SEVERAL of the sources I found confirm that there is scrotal shrinkage that occurs post-op. So, maybe this is not the case in all dogs, and the degree to which it happens varies drastically from dog to dog, but saying they are wrong without any qualifiers seems a bit off.

This is a community for human medical science, not veterinary science.

Not an answer, but I appreciate that you've added sources. My guess (because of what the body ordinarily does) is that it's multifactorial. It does shrink, the degree varying slightly with age. Some scrotal skin elements atrophy/thin in the absence of testosterone. The fluid that normally surrounds the testes is resorbed. The muscle fibers contract some. Probably more, too. The procedure is called an orchiectomy; searching post-orchiectomy scrotal changes might get you more info.

@IanCampbell - Your comment is ironic, considering how important dogs are in the understanding of human disease. I can think of several diseases off the bat  the etiology of which we now understand largely or solely because of dogs.

@anongoodnurse I would be more convinced if this question were about a dog model of a human medical condition. But as written, humans are just a tangential (and therefore overly broad) afterthought to a dog phenomenon. I'm happy to send this to Biology or Pets, but I worry it won't be better received. I do agree that it has substantial prior research included.

@IanCampbell - Humans have orchiectomies too, with the same results. Do with it what you will; I think to classify this as veterinary medicine is viewing "medicine" through a pretty narrow window (or two).
